# Count the amount of users that are logged in

Tags: php, database, authentication

I am working on a school project. The assignment is to recreate our own version of Ebay. A requirement is to display the number of logged in users. What is the best way to do this? We are using PHP.

We are using a database so we could save the amount of loggins there but there is no proper way to decrease this amount since people often just leave the site without logging out.

Some suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: In my project I'm using a status column which updates on login and logout. when a user logs in, it sets to online, when user logs off, it sets to offline. you can then do this by using an integer `(1, 0)` 1 for online and 0 for offline and then query on `where status = 1`

Comment: what if user doesn't log out explicitly? @Jbadminton

Comment: Yes I though about that, however this only works when a user actively clicks the 'log out' button. But if someone just closes their browser, the status column won't update to 0.

Comment: Then you should keep a datetime and let the session expire after about 10 minutes and only update the datetime of last login when a user logs in, in that way you have a list of logged in users from the last 10 minutes

Comment: You probably need server sent events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events and a body unload event handler to update your database with logouts.

Comment: You can also look at establishing socket connections.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have a heartbeat script that updates a datetime on the user column.

and the show logged in users script could get all logged in users with time < 5 mins

Comment: Ah this is good idea! I am going to try this!

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: awsome! whist this isnt the most robust solution for a production server it will be ideal for hobby/school